# SharPoint 2013 - Can I add a Snippet panel from the Ribbon onto a Publishing Page?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout

Within SharePoint 2013, on a publishing page, in edit mode, is there a way for us to write snippet right on SharePoint publishing page rather than directly on the .htm custom page layout?  I want to write...

```
<!--SPM:<asp:LoginView id="mGroupA" runat="server"> -->
<!--SPM:<RoleGroups>-->
<!--SPM:<asp:RoleGroup Roles="GroupA">-->
<!--SPM:<ContentTemplate>-->

<h2>Yes! Only Group A can now see this stuff!</h2>

<!--SPM:</ContentTemplate>-->
<!--SPM:</asp:RoleGroup>-->
<!--SPM:</RoleGroups>-->
<!--SPM:</asp:LoginView>-->
```

If not is there an alternative approach to the publishing page that will give me the same effect?

Comment: You mean you want to enable portion of the page only to people belonging to a particular group?

Comment: Yes and I want to write to apply that logic from the sharepoint page, not from the custom page layout.

Comment: Have you tried editing the page in SPD and placing that code without <!--SPM: and -->

Comment: I don't want to do that because I will have other pages with content that depends on what role you are in.  I will have 20 other pages.  Instead I want to edit a sharepoint publishing page and either write or insert the conditional logic there.

Comment: This is what I want to do - http://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/custom-authoring-snippets-in-sharepoint-2013#.VMADOkfF9tQ